# How to check for unused modules in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular 9, and I've the following module declaration

```
const moduleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [HomeService],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(moduleRoutes),
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    RouterModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
  ]
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

How can I check if all the "imports" are needed? Is there a tool that can handle this task for me?

Comment: I don’t know about a tool what I usually do is that after I finish changing my source code I remove all imports and use Rider’s (I think all angular supported jetbrains app can do this) alt+enter mechanism to import all needed modules. (Also rider warns you if a module is missing so you can try removing them one-by-one)

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659508/determining-the-unused-angular-modules-at-the-app-module-ts-file

Comment: LOL Adding a duplicate that doesn't have an answer

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I had to do this myself, there are definitely tools out there to help you :)

1. Option 1: `npm install -g depcheck`
2. Option 2: `yarn global add depcheck` *or if you are using Yarn*
3. CD over to the folder where you want your dependencies to be checked. Then run:

---

**Bonus help**

Many of the answers here are how to find unused items.

I wanted to **remove them automatically**.

1. Install this node project:

   `npm install -g typescript tslint tslint-etc`
2. At the root dir, add a new file `tslint-imports.json`:

   ```
   {
     "extends": [
       "tslint-etc"
     ],
     "rules": {
       "no-unused-declaration": true
     }
   }
   ```
3. Run this at your own risk, make a backup :)

   ```
   tslint --config tslint-imports.json --fix --project .

   depcheck
   ```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck#usage

Comment: @Gavi did you try this?

Comment: This is about npm package dependencies, the OP is about Angular modules.